# Magento import image problem

Tags: magento2, import, product-images

When i import a csv file with product everythings is ok. Images are on admin product page. But in frontend there is nothing, just the broken image with the alt.

When i go to the image in admin and i press save (i do nothing, just direct save) the image appear in frontend.

I already try : `setup:static-content:deploy` `index:reindex` `cache:clean`

I don't know if you understand well, my english isn't very good.

Comment: Have you done indexing after product import. Might be that could be issue.

Comment: hi, yes sorry, i edit my post to add what i've done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following menthod:

1.Please check your imported csv file inside column `product_websites` is empty or filled with `base`.

2.Do image resize  `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Comment: Yours welcome @Nundra

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rows in your CSV:

- base_image
- base_image_label
- thumbnail_image
- thumbnail_image_labe
- small_image
- small_image_label

You have to upload the product images to Magento 2 pub/media/import folder.

**Note:** Make sure that all the images that you upload have the same name as in CSV.

Then upload the CSV file and enter /pub/media/import in the Image File Directory text field. Lastly, import the CSV.

Comment: Hi, i already do this, my problem is the image are in backend,but not in front end. I use the images:resize and it's ok.